# Codeigniter page routing

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I'm new to Codeigniter and i have a problem in page routing. I have a button placed in my first page

```
<center><a href="" class="button1">Start</a></center>
```

I have a page in my view folder. I want to direct to this page when i click my button. How can i navigate to my page in view folder on button click.

My base url

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/xampp/CodeIgniter/';
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could leave it empty as codeigniter would use the default application path: `$config['base_url'] = '';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using codeigniter, you could simply name the function in the contorller that would load the page you want.

```
<center><a href="<?=base_url().'ControllerName/functionName';?>" class="button1">Start</a></center>
```

or depending on your configurations:

```
<center><a href="<?=base_url().'index.php/ControllerName/functionName';?>" class="button1">Start</a></center>
```

in the controllerName and the functionName:

```
// Other code ...
$this->load->view('viewFileName');
```

Comment: Then I guess you have to include index.php in your path: <?=base_url().'index.php/ControllerName/functionName';?>

Comment: Thank you it worked.. but i don't understand why i have to include index.php . can u explain a bit? thank you again

Comment: The index.php appears in your URLs because it is the file responsible for processing all requests to the system. In a URL such as http://example.com/index.php/template_group/template, the template_group/template segments are simply information passed to index.php and do not refer to actual files or folders in the server’s filesystem. But you can remove it from the urls as explained in: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html (Althought it still gets executed)

Answer (score 0):

First you need enable url library

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

then test base_url(); function

Returns your site base URL, as specified in your config file. Example:

```
echo base_url();
```

And Calling view page, Suppose your file name is home.php

```
<?php
class Example extends CI_Controller {

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('home');
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First load `url_helper` by

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Or in your `autoload.php` set

```
$autoload['helper'] = ['url'];
```

Then

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url() ?>" class="button1">Start</a>
```

> Note: Use `site_url()` instead of `base_url()`, `base_url()` suited
>   for src like
>
> ```
> <img src="<?php echo base_url()" /> ....
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Your base url is incorrect

replcae

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/xampp/CodeIgniter/';
```

to'

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/CodeIgniter/';
```

then

```
<center><a href="<?php site_url('ControllerName/functionName');?>" class="button1">Start</a></center>
```

Read this tutorial for more http://w3code.in/2015/10/codeigniter-installation-beginner-guide/